# Youtube video as background for specific section

Tags: css, youtube

I need to make a youtube video as a background for a specific section not the whole page.
So I need for section to be 390px height and 100% width.

Right now I am using this code but the problem is that the youtube iframe is 100% full width but the video itself is very small and with black sidebars.
here is the code:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
   <div id="player"></div>
</div>

<script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '100%',
                videoId: 'EhArkyWXpO0',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });

        }


        // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
        //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
        //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
        var done = false;
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
            }
        }
        function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }

</script>
```

I am using youtube API and Im setting 100% width in javascript.
I am pretty sure I have to use css to achieve this, but no success so far...

Here is the current output
[image]

My desired output would be the wideo without black sidebars

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the width with javascript by settings `width` to the width of your window or the parent node.

Set the size of the parent node to 100% and try something like:

```
node = document.getElementById("player");
player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: node.parentNode.offsetWidth * 9 / 16,
    width: node.parentNode.offsetWidth,
    videoId: 'EhArkyWXpO0',
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
)
```

If you want to adjust the size if the window is resized, you have to add a function to `window.onresize`:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var node = document.getElementById('player');
    // fetch player; may a childnode of node[id="player"]
    player.setAttribute("width", node.parentNode.offsetWidth);
};
```

Comment: The black sidebars are a result of the video-screen-resolution (e.g. 16:9, 4:3, ...). You can calculate the height of the container by the resolution so that width / height = 16 / 9. That will remove the "black sidebars"

Comment: Can you please drop an example how would you achieve that?

Comment: Done. Edited the answer. The math: width / height = 16 / 9 => height =  width * 9 / 16

Comment: Ok it almoust does the trick. I just need to reduce height to 390px. For now it just removes the black sidebars but the video is very big